# prove that $f(x)=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}\frac{1}{\alpha !}D^{\alpha}f(0)x^{\alpha} + O(|x|^{k+1})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

If $\alpha$ is multiindex and $f$ is smooth,prove that $f(x)=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}\frac{1}{\alpha !}D^{\alpha}f(0)x^{\alpha} + O(|x|^{k+1})$. The hint is to use taylors form for $g(t)=f(tx)$. If i do this i will found that
$g(t)=\sum \frac{g^{n}(0)}{n!}t^n = \sum \frac{ D^nf(0)x^n t^n}{n!}$. How i continued? i need to do induction over size of $\alpha$. Any hint please, thank you.

Comment: You incorrectly computed $g^{(n)}(0)$ (note that $f^{(n)}$ does not make sense since $f$ is a multivariate function). Be careful when using the chain rule with the total derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to show using the chain rule that $$g^{(n)}(0) = \sum_{|\alpha| = n} D^\alpha f(0) x^\alpha.$$
Combining with your first step and plugging in $t=1$ yields $$f(x) = g(1) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{1}{|\alpha|!}\sum_{|\alpha| = n} D^\alpha f(0) x^\alpha.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think that need a litle more please, don't need induction over size of $\alpha$ thank you